# org-mode: Schedule a task multiple times

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I plan to meet with someone multiple times, but not on a regular schedule that would allow me to set it as a repeating task. I can type in something like

```
** TODO Meeting with Gus
   SCHEDULED: <2014-04-25 FRI 10:00-10:30>
   SCHEDULED: <2014-04-28 MON 15:30-16:00>
```

Scheduling the first meeting using <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> (`org-schedule`) is easy enough. I cannot find a way to schedule the second without typing everything in by hand. If I hit <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> again, it changes the time of the first meeting rather than scheduling a second meeting. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about:

```
** Meet with a dude
   <2014-04-25 Fri 13:00-13:30>
   <2014-04-27 Sun 14:00-14:30>
   <2014-04-29 Tue 10:00-10:30>
   <2014-05-02 Fri 08:00-08:30>
```

This will show up in your agenda at the indicated times.

Comment: You're correct. I should be using simple timestamps rather than scheduling. From the org-mode manual: "Setting a date for a meeting is just a simple appointment, you should mark this entry with a simple plain timestamp, to get this item shown on the date where it applies. This is a frequent misunderstanding by Org users. In Org mode, scheduling means setting a date when you want to start working on an action item."